# Putting an object in an array AFTER it's loaded, React Native

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, react-native-flatlist, asyncstorage

I'm trying to put an object into an array with an async function but the array is filled earlier than the object is loaded thus putting an empty object inside of the array.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Button, FlatList, Image, Text, Pressable } from 'react-native';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';


import ShoppingCart from '../components/CartItem';


const CartScreen = ({ navigation, route }) => {

  const [newItem, setNewItem] = useState([]);
  const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState([]);
  
  const getData = async () => {
    try{
      AsyncStorage.getItem('@cartItem')
      .then((value) => {
        if (value != null) {
          let itemdata = JSON.parse(value);
          setNewItem(itemdata);
          setCartItems((currentItems) => [...currentItems, newItem]);
        }
      })
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);



  return(

  <View style={styles.screen}>

    <Pressable onPress={() => {
      console.log(newItem);
      console.log(newItem.itemID);
      console.log(cartItems);
    }}>
      <ShoppingCart title={newItem.itemID}/>
    </Pressable>

    <FlatList
      keyExtractor={item => item.itemID}
      data={cartItems}
      renderItem={(item) => (
        <ShoppingCart
        title={item.item.itemTitle}
        />
        )}
    
    />

  </View>

  );

}
```

In this code you can see I parse the string from `@cartItem` into `newItem`.

(I made a button on the screen to console.log and I can see that the data is correctly inside of `newItem`. )
[saving the file and pressing the log button once](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gb2A.png)

Then I put this `newItem` inside of `cartItems`, which is an array that acts as the data for my flatlist with shoppingcart items.
This is where the funny thing happens. It first puts an empty array inside of `cartItems`, which I guess happens because `newItem` hasn't gotten its loaded data from the AsyncStorage yet. Now when I ctrl+s to save this file (DetailsScreen.js) it updates (because of the useEffect I suppose) and puts the `newItem` correctly into `cartItems` but now there's an empty array and the right object in my flatlist.
[when getting on the screen and pressing the button to log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7A9k.png)

**How can I make sure that `newItem` has gotten its value first before it gets put inside of `cartItems`?** Or is this not the problem at all?

I have tried to use

```
  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, [newItem]);
```

which makes an infiniteloop because it keeps updating, same for replacing `newItem` with `cartItems`.

I also notice there's some weird stuff going around with my flatlist where I have to put `item.item.itemTitle` instead of `item.itemTitle`, if anyone knows what's up with that.

Full project on my GitHub https://github.com/ArneSamson/ReactNative-store-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`newItem` wont have be updated until the next render. So in this code

```js
let itemdata = JSON.parse(value);
setNewItem(itemdata);
setCartItems((currentItems) => [...currentItems, newItem]);
```

`newItem` hasnt yet been updated to `itemdata`'s value. The easiest way around this is to simply use itemdata to update cartItems:

```js
let itemdata = JSON.parse(value);
setNewItem(itemdata);
setCartItems((currentItems) => [...currentItems, itemdata]);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this indeed worked.I knew it was probably something simple I overlooked.